# R read.csv colClasses scan() expected 'a logical', got '"FALSE"'

Tags: r, csv, class, import

I'm reading a 25-column csv using `read.csv` with `colClasses` specified. The penultimate column is `logical` so I specified `"logical"` in the `colClasses` and got the error

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  scan() expected 'a logical', got '"FALSE"'
```

If I read in the file without `colClasses` - `read.csv(file = i)` - it works fine AND the column is imported as logical! Similarly if I use `colClasses` but label that column as `NA`. The column's unique values are `NA` `FALSE` `TRUE`. Opening the file in LibreOffice Calc, the entries are unquoted i.e. `FALSE` and not `"FALSE"`.

Can anyone think why this is happening? It seems highly unintuitive / buglike - though experience has taught me it's 99% likely to be me doing something stupid!

Thanks